# Understanding dimension of Goppa code

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography, coding-theory

My concern is regarding the understanding of the dimension of Goppa Codes and the corresponding dimension of its parity check matrix. The classical definition often referred to as **classical view** of Goppa Code is given by the set:

$$\Gamma : = \{ c \in \mathbb{F}_{2}^{n} \hspace3pt  | \hspace3pt  S(c) =  \frac{c_{1}}{x - a_{1}} + \frac{c_{2}}{x - a_{2}} + \cdots + \frac{c_{n}}{x - a_{n}} \mod g = 0 \}$$

where, each element in the sequence of code locators $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ is an element of $\mathbb{F}_{{2}^{m}}$, $g$ is a square free polynomial of degree $t$ in $\mathbb{F}_{{2}^m}[x]$ such that $g(a_i) \neq 0 \hspace 6 pt\forall i \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, for example an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{{2}^m}[x]$.

**My understanding:** 
$S$ is a linear combination of polynomials $\frac{1}{x - a_i}$ each of degree at most $t-1$. This is because: 
$g(a_i) \neq 0 \implies gcd((x - a_i), g) = 1 \implies \exists (x - a_i)^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}_{{2}^m}[x] / g $. 
$$\implies (x - a_i)^{-1} \equiv p_{i}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} p_{i,j} \cdot x^j \mod g$$.

With the help of the above form, we can represent the polynomial $S$ in $\Gamma$ as:
$$S(c) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i \large(\sum_{j=0}^{t-1} p_{i,j} \cdot x^j \large)$$
$$ \iff S(c) = \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} \large(\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \cdot p_{i,j}  \large)x^j $$.
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \cdot p_{i,j} = 0 $$.

From the literature, I read that the parity-check matrix which is basically a matrix whose right-kernel space forms the set of the linear code, that is, $H \cdot c^{T} = 0 \hspace3pt \forall c \in \Gamma.$

**My Question**
I can not understand why the kernel matrix $H$ has the dimension $mt \times n$. Can someone please help me to understand how does the factor $m$ come about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your symbols crossed, or there is a typo.

Dimension is usually referred to by $k.$ The parity check matrix is actually size $tm\times n$. The dimension is $$k\geq n-tm$$ since some of those rows might be linearly dependent.

See the talk by Tanja Lange [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qisORKNShvo&t=207s) where she carefully explains this.

Comment: Thank you for the resource and  pointing out my typo, it in fact is a typo. The 'k' should be infact  a 't' to be consistent with above definition of dimension of the parity check matrix. I checked the lecture which indeed is a great explanation of the goopa code basics. I understand that there must be 't' conditions over F_(2^m) however, again I couldn't understand why there are exactly 'mt' condition over $\mathbb{F}_2$, can you please help me understand this?

Comment: This is because $F_{2^m}$ has dimension $m$ over $F_2$. So each condition, when expressed in binary contributes $m$ dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, now I am able to follow the reason.